# Custom Android activities transition

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I am trying to mimic the Android twitter application activities transition. 
but i don't get the same effect.
Can someone suggest a way to do it.
thanks

Comment: This question is about to be closed. If you want to keep it open, you need to provide more content. For example, where is the code you have tried, and what does the twitter app do (screenshots/video would be nice)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

In your first Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExample);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Test.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

    }
```

slide_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

fade_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

The first Activity will now fade out and the second Activity will slide in from the right side.